# Controlling Frequency of a Vibration Motor with Battery Voltage Output

Tags: frequency, voltage-measurement, battery-operated, vibration, vibration-motor

I am looking to operate a Vibration motor at a sustained frequency (40Hz) Please see data sheet as below with an example of a motor. I understand that the best way to do this is to control the output Voltage of the Battery (as per below sheet) this will be approx 0.8 V to get the desired frequency - How would I go about controlling the output of the Voltage? or is there an alternative better way to achieve this frequency. Please excuse my lack of knowledge, any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Depends on what you already have available in your system, but PWM is the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 2):

This motor is barely spinning at 40 Hz.  Just applying the voltage indicated by the graph is not going to be very reliable.  Some motors under some conditions may not spin at all.

Especially since you're at the edge of the motor's operation, you need feedback to control the frequency.  The whole system would be too much to get into detail about here, but basically there are three parts, frequency sensing, the control algorithm, and a means of adjusting the current or voltage delivered to the motor.

A small piezo sensor might be a good choice for the frequency sensing.  A suitable circuit would amplify and filter this, and present the result to a microcontroller.  Since you only care about 40 Hz, you can run the signal into a A/D input.  This simplifies the analog electronics between the sensor and the micro.

The micro implements the control algorithm in firmware, probably running each A/D reading, at a few kHz.  The result of the algorithm is the *control output*, which is a number that goes up when the motor is too slow, and down when the motor is too fast.

The simplest way to drive the motor roughly proportional to the control output is via PWM.  Just about every micro has hardware to produce the PWM pulses for you.  After you set it up, all you do is write the control value to a register, and the PWM duty cycle changes as a result.  The PWM pulses control a transistor used as a low side switch.

I'd try to run the PWM at 24 kHz or maybe a bit higher.  That still results in a "long" pulse period for the purpose of minimizing switching losses, but is fast enough to be above most people's hearing, and won't let the current thru the motor coils change much in one pulse time.

Don't forget the flyback catch diode in reverse across the motor.  At this low voltage, that should definitely be a Schottky.

Comment: rotation rate estimation should be possible, and probably easier, to do directly from variation in the current drawn by the motor than by employing a piezo; this feels like the classical university lab example where you estimate the angle of a weight added to a disc by observing the U/I behaviour, just easier.

Comment: @Marcus: I had actually thought of suggesting that as a alternative.  However, these things are brushed DC motors, and have a lot of noise on the current.  What you say can be done, but it's more "advanced" than getting a waveform from a piezo transducer.  At the level the OP is apparently at, I didn't think getting into the nuances of detecting speed from watching current made sense.  As it is, I suspect my answer is already largely over the OP's head.  He asked a broad question, so no room to get into details.

Comment: very true. Still, I think we both agree that sensing current over a shunt R and low-pass filtering with an RC LPF it might be easier in the end than integrating the piezo (whose signal isn't that trivial to interpret, either! ), since you'd need, for Nyquist reasons, to LPF anyway.